# execute set of commands in group by {} vs ()

Tags: bash, command-line, command

I read this post:

- [How do I run multiple background commands in bash in a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612371/how-do-i-run-multiple-background-commands-in-bash-in-a-single-line)

I understand the answer, but having the option to execute a set of commands through either `{}` or `()` makes to create this post.

If the scenario(s) exists: when is mandatory use `{}` over `()` - and vice versa - and why?

Comment: `( )` create a subshell, not `{ }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between both is that `()` create a subshell.
For example, you can try this:

```
cd $HOME ; ls
```

The output with those commands will list the files and directories you have for the current user.

Now, using subshell, you can try this:

```
( cd / ; ls ; ) ; ls
```

What we are doing here is creating a subshell **(cd / ; ls)** for changing the current directory to `/` and then, list its files and directories.
After that, once the subshells ends we list the files of the current directory but this is not the `/` dir, in this case the current directory is  user home folder (**$HOME**)

Now if you change the `()` for `{}` the behavior will be different.

```
{ cd / ; ls ; } ; ls
```

Here, the output will list the files and dirs in the `/` directory for both `ls` commands.

Let's check another example:

```
( echo Subshell is $BASH_SUBSHELL ; ) ; echo Subshell is $BASH_SUBSHELL
```

Those commands will echo respectively:

```
Subshell is 1
Subshell is 0
```

As you can see, using the environment variable `$BASH_SUBSHELL` you can get the current subshell level you are, so, when you use `()` the `BASH_SUBSHELL` changes (you can use nested subshell as you want).

And another more example:

```
( vartmp=10 ; echo var is $vartmp ; ) ; echo var is $vartmp
```

In this case, the output will be:

```
var is 10
var is
```

As you can see,in the second line the `$vartmp` is empty. This is correct, because when a subshell ends with the execution, all variables, functions and some changes (like modifying a environment variable) will get cleared.
So, when you want to display the `$vartmp` after subshells ends, the output will be empty because the variable doesn't exist.

You can try changing the `()` to `{}` in those commands to check the different behaviors.